# Why use subjunctive here?

Tags: subjunctive

In Demian, Hermann Hess writes:

> Da war stets die Heimkehr zum Vater und zum Guten so erlösend und großartig, ich empfand durchaus, daß dies allein das Richtige, Gute und Wünschenswerte **sei**, ...

Why does Hess use "**sei**" here and not "**ist**"?

Comment: Why do you think that subjunctive is inappropriate here?

Comment: Because I do not know of a reason to prefer it to the present tense, in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subjunctive mood (as it exists in English) and and conjunctive mood (as it exists in two variations in German) are similar, but not identical. So, I prefer to call it *conjunctive mood.*

What is used in your example is German conjunctive I (Konjunktiv I). German verbs have a special form that has to be used when you want to build a sentence containing conjunctive I.

> The verbs in the examples are: to be, to eat, to sleep
>
> Indikativ: Er ist hier. Er isst. Er schläft.
> Konjunktiv I: Man sagt, er sei hier. Man sagt, er esse. Man sagt, er schlafe.
> Konjunktiv II: Nehmen wir an, er wäre hier. Nehmen wir an, er äße. Nehmen wir an, er schliefe.

Rule of thumb:

- Indikativ: Something that really happens.
- Konjunktiv I: When indirect speech is used.
- Konjunktiv II: If you talk about a possibility that is not real.

But there is more.

Use **Konjunktiv I** in these cases:

- indirect speech

  > Paul sagt mir, er **sei** in Lisa verliebt.
- Indirect considerations

  > Paul überlegt, wie er Lisa ansprechen **könne.**
- Indirect questions

  > Paul fragt Lisa, ob sie mit ihm ins Kino **gehe.**
- Assumptions

  > Paul glaubte, Lisa **habe** bereits einen Freund.
- Requirements

  > Lisa forderte von Paul, dass er ihr ewig treu **sei.**
- Wishes

  > Beide hofften, ihr Glück **möge** ewig währen.

Your example is an assumption. *"Ich empfand" (I felt)* and  *"ich glaubte" (I believed)* almost have the same meaning.

(There are even more different use-cases for Konjunktiv II.)

Comment: There is a good summary of Subjunktive I/Konjunktiv I/Special Subjunctive/Whatever [here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Subjunctive/KonjunktivI.html).

Comment: Gute Antwort. Bist du sicher bei "überlegen"? Ich habe das, glaube ich, noch nie mit dem Konjuktiv I gehört, sondern meistens mit Indikativ oder mit Konjunktiv II. Eben genau, weil es unter "a possibility that is not real" fällt.

Comment: @HalvarF: ja, ich bin da ziemlich sicher. Siehe auch [Link1](http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Konjunktiv.htm) und [Link2](http://home.datacomm.ch/bezaarau/konjunktiv.html), wobei ich nicht weiß, wer da von wem geklaut hat (Gemeint ist der Satz »Sascha dachte pausenlos darüber nach, wie er sie ansprechen könne.«)