# Help in understanding the use of the present subjunctive use of sein

Tags: subjunctive

Reading Peter Stamm book "Die sanfte Gleichgűltigkeit der Welt" in the first chapter came across this sentence.

"Es ist mir, als sei ich Teil dieser Landschaft geworden, die sich in all der Zeit kaum verändert hat."

Why is the subjunctive of sein "sei" used in this sentence?  It refers back to "Es ist mir".

Comment: "Es scheint so" "Ich habe das Gefühl/ den Eindruck" "Es kommt mir so vor, als sei ich ...geworden" --> 2. Reporting Thoughts, Beliefs, Opinions

This is an extension of Subjunctive I’s basic function of reporting speech:

    `Er dachte, sie sei vom Mars
    He thought she was from Mars

    Er glaubte, sie werde ihn entführen
    He believed she would abduct him`
https://resources.german.lsa.umich.edu/grammatik/konjunktiv1/

Comment: Similar: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61034/why-use-subjunctive-here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is meant like:
*"Es scheint so"*, *"Ich habe das Gefühl/ den Eindruck..."* *"Es kommt mir so vor, als sei ich ... geworden"*

Copied from [german.lsa](https://resources.german.lsa.umich.edu/grammatik/konjunktiv1/):

### Konjunktiv I [Subjunctive I]:

**2. Reporting Thoughts, Beliefs, Opinions**

This is an extension of Subjunctive I’s basic function of reporting speech:

**sei**:

> Er dachte, sie **sei** vom Mars.

> He thought she was from Mars.

**werde**:

> Er glaubte, sie **werde** ihn entführen

> He believed she would abduct him